Redis is giving error connection refused in openwhisk
I am using k3s to deploy the openwhisk on ubuntu machine.everything is working fine except invoker pods are not able to access redis server which is running inside same namespace.
when I am trying to access the redis server from wskopenwhisk-invoker-00-27-prewarm-nodejs10 .I am getting connection refused.I have network policy.Not sure if network policy is the reason behind it.
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                       AGE
openwhisk-kafka        ClusterIP   None                    9092/TCP                      4h21m
openwhisk-zookeeper    ClusterIP   None                    2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP    4h21m
openwhisk-couchdb      ClusterIP   10...*            5984/TCP                      4h21m
openwhisk-redis        ClusterIP   10...*            6379/TCP                      4h21m
openwhisk-apigateway   ClusterIP   10...*             8080/TCP,9000/TCP             4h21m
openwhisk-controller   ClusterIP   10...*               8080/TCP                      4h21m
openwhisk-nginx        NodePort    10...*   192.168.8.19   81:32498/TCP,4430:31001/TCP   4h21m
pods
NAME                                               READY   STATUS      RESTARTS         AGE
openwhisk-apigateway-897477798-k4ncs               1/1     Running     0                4h22m
openwhisk-wskadmin                                 1/1     Running     0                4h22m
openwhisk-couchdb-66dbd6585-pw75n                  1/1     Running     0                4h22m
openwhisk-redis-7cbbb965b8-85cpg                   1/1     Running     0                4h22m
openwhisk-zookeeper-0                              1/1     Running     0                4h22m
openwhisk-kafka-0                                  1/1     Running     0                4h22m
openwhisk-controller-0                             1/1     Running     0                4h22m
openwhisk-nginx-7889cc6f95-925sz                   1/1     Running     0                4h22m
openwhisk-invoker-0                                1/1     Running     0                120m
wskopenwhisk-invoker-00-27-prewarm-nodejs10        1/1     Running     0                104m
tried removing the network policy but no luck
